# Want to get region name from drill down map of jvectormap

Tags: jvectormap

I am unable to get region name from code of region. My region click event work fine and I also get code properly. My code is:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        new jvm.MultiMap({
            container: $('#map'),
            maxLevel: 1,
            main: {
                map: 'us_lcc_en'
            },
            mapUrlByCode: function (code, multiMap) {
                return 'js/counties/jquery-jvectormap-data-' +
                   code.toLowerCase() + '-' +
                   multiMap.defaultProjection + '-en.js';
            }
        });


        $('#map').bind('regionClick.jvectormap', function (event, code) {
            var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
            alert(map.getRegionName(code));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
 alert(map.getRegionName(code));  These lines are not working...

Comment: I have posted a working solution below. you can have a look. accepted answer does not even seems to execute. it will give error. If you can check my answer it will be great as it may help other people also that may go through same problem. I have used this in my project so just think of posting it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this code

```
onRegionClick:function(event, code) {                        
        var name = (code);                        
        alert(name);                    
        }
```

All Script Like This

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        new jvm.MultiMap({
            container: $('#map'),
            maxLevel: 1,
            main: {
                map: 'us_lcc_en'
            },
            mapUrlByCode: function (code, multiMap) {
                return 'js/counties/jquery-jvectormap-data-' +
                   code.toLowerCase() + '-' +
                   multiMap.defaultProjection + '-en.js';
            }
        });


     onRegionClick:function(event, code) {                        
        var name = (code);                        
        alert(name);                    
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How can you use on regionclick outside of map block. I mean on region click in your code is under only $(function () { block how it can even execute. i have improved this in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="map2" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
  $('#map2').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        series: {
        regions: [{
            scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            values: gdpData
          }]
        },
        onRegionClick: function (event, code) {


          ******* Code To Show Region Name *******

          /* Here We are getting Map Object */
          var map=$('#map2').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');

          /* Here Using Map Object we are using Inbuilt GetRegionName 
          function TO Get Regionname for a region Code */

          var regionName = map.getRegionName(code);
          console.log("Code: "+code+"<br/>");
          console.log("Region Name: "+regionName+"<br/>");

          ******* Code To Show Region Name *******
        }

      });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question as the OP is asking about a MultiMap and this answer is for a plain vectorMap. My answer below can accomplish what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to get the region name from the onRegionClick for a multi map. This is my hack to get what is needed.

```
            var drillDownUSMap;
            var stateCode;
            var countyName;

            $(document).ready(function () {
                drillDownUSMap = new jvm.MultiMap({
                    container: $('#map'),
                    maxLevel: 1,
                    main: {
                        map: 'us_lcc_en',
                        onRegionClick: function (e, code) {
                            var map = $('#map div').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
                            var regionName = map.getRegionName(code);
                            stateCode = code.toLowerCase();
                            console.log(regionName)
                        }
                    },
                    mapUrlByCode: function (code, multiMap) {
                        return 'js/counties/jquery-jvectormap-data-' +
                            code.toLowerCase() + '-' +
                            multiMap.defaultProjection + '-en.js';
                    },
                    mapNameByCode: function (code, multiMap) {
                        return code.toLowerCase() + '_' +
                            multiMap.defaultProjection + '_en';
                    }
                });

                $(document).on('click', '.jvectormap-region.jvectormap-element', function (evt) {
                    var regionElem = $(this);
                    var stateJSFileName = stateCode + "_" + drillDownUSMap.defaultProjection + "_en";
                    var regionCode = regionElem.attr('data-code');
                    if (drillDownUSMap.maps[stateJSFileName]) {
                        countyName = drillDownUSMap.maps[stateJSFileName].regions[regionCode].config.name;
                        if (regionElem.hasClass("selected-region")) {
                            regionElem.removeClass("selected-region");
                        } else {
                            regionElem.addClass("selected-region");
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
```